# Regex: Capture everything up until a character sequence & if that character sequence doesn't exist, capture entire text

Tags: regex, expression, sequence, capture

**Aim:**
Capture everything up until a character sequence & if those character sequences don't exist, capture entire text.

Character sequences:
**| table** &
**| stats**

Ex 1:
`search foo bar | table _time Action Direction`
returns `search foo bar`

Ex 2:
`search foo bar hello hi ciao 1234`
returns `search foo bar hello hi ciao 1234`

Ex 3:
`search foo bar`
`bar foo`
`| table _time Action Direction`

returns
`search foo bar`
`bar foo`

Current solution which doesn't satisfy Ex 2:

**(?<var>(?s).+?(?=\Q| table\E|\Q| stats\E))**

You can use https://regex101.com/ for testing.
Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?s)^(?<var>.*?(?=\| (?:table|stats)|$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LtRd59/1/).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - singleline/dotall modifier on
- `^` - start of string
- `(?<var>.*?(?=\| (?:table|stats)|$))` - Group "var":

  - `.*?` - zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of
  - `(?=\| (?:table|stats)|$)` - either `|`+space+`table` or `stats`, or end of string.

Comment: Thank you this is almost what I want! How could I get it to capture line breaks?
E.g.
search foo bar<br>
bar foo<br>
| table _time Action Direction

returns:
search foo bar<br>
bar foo<br>

Comment: @JohnoCown `.` with `(?s)` matches line breaks

Comment: @JohnoCown Please show a test case via https://regex101.com/r/LtRd59/1/ if it does not like you expect

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eznV0R/1 I would like this to capture everything except the last line (|table ....) in a single match

Comment: @JohnoCown It does what you want if you remove the `g` modifier, the first match returns you what you want, see https://regex101.com/r/eznV0R/3. If you show the code, I will help more.

Comment: This worked well - thanks for your help!!